# filter objects by relations tastypie "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable"

Tags: django, filter, neo4j, relationship, tastypie

I'm using the tastypie API and a neo4j database with Django 1.5.3. & Neo4django. I would like to access/filter e.g. a Lemma(s) that are related to Words with a specific pos value via the API.

models.py

```
class Lemma(models.NodeModel):

    value = models.StringProperty(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.value

class Word(models.NodeModel):

    pos = models.StringProperty(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
    cid = models.IntegerProperty(blank=True, null=True)

    lemma = models.Relationship(Lemma,
                                rel_type='has_base',
                                single=True,
                                related_name='values'
                               )    
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.value
```

api.py:

```
class LemmaResource(ModelResource):

    word = fields.ToManyField('api.api.WordResource', 'values', related_name='lemma', null=True )

    class Meta:
        queryset = Lemma.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'lemma'
        always_return_data = True
        excludes = ['require_order', 'require_all']
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization()
        filtering = {'value': ALL,
            'word': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS}


class WordResource(ModelResource):

    lemma = fields.ToOneField(LemmaResource, 'lemma', null=True )

    class Meta:
        queryset = Word.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'word'
        always_return_data = True
        excludes = ['require_order', 'require_all']
        authorization = ReadOnlyAuthorization()
        filtering = {'CTS': ALL,
                'lemma': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
                'pos': ALL}
```

I tried to follow this example ([Filtering on reverse relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13382265/filtering-on-reverse-relations)) I would like to call via the API e.g. ../api/lemma/?word__pos=noun&format=json , but I got an "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" ERROR. Do I have to name the filters as in the model calsses or should that be the filed names? Could it be that the neo4j database makes some problems.

I appreciate any hints. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to allow filtering on word (ALL_WITH_RELATIONS) in your lemma ModelResource, since you're trying to... well, filter on word in your lemma Resource :)

Comment: yes, sure. This was a trial of desperation. It wouldn't work either, ERROR stays. =)